# Do I need an emergency septic pumping or to have pipes cleaned when toilets flood after cleaning filter?

Tags: septic

I own a rental property with a septic tank built in 2010.  There are about 5 people living there and it was last pumped out 18 months ago.  Their toilets started flooding yesterday.  I dug out the solid waste tank and found the water level was up to the top, over the filter.  I fished out the filter and found it was certainly dirty but not obviously clogged. I cleaned it some.  While it was out the water level dropped below the level of the pipe containing the filter.  I put the filter back in and restored the cover.  Later last night the tenant said both toilets were flooding again, apparently from the bottom.  My questions are is this a pumping emergency or is the current problem that some pipe is still clogged and needs to be cleared?

Comment: Well, when the water is up high, there'd be little velocity in the pipes. Solids would tend to settle in the pipes instead of being carried away, so yeah, I would expect some clogs. I don't see what you did to correct the original problem, though... what's the strategy here?

Comment: So far I cleaned out the filter in the tank and opened the cap to relieve pressure in the pipe

Comment: Your tank was full of water is it not draining your field may be plugged. What kind of filter ? Is this a pumped system? Has there been a lot of rain in your area? Lots of questions.

Comment: There has not been a lot of rain.  I went ahead with getting it pumped out, but it seems like the immediate problem was a clog in the line just above the pump tank, possibly caused by material sitting there when the filter was clogged.  The tech pumping the tank ran a snake through the pipe and that seems to have resolved the issue.